# Inherit DependencyProperties

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have created several UserControls like a *HeaderedDatePicker*.

The XAML of this `UserControl` looks like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Book.CustomControls.HeaderedDatePicker"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             Width="200" Height="50">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Header}" FontWeight="{Binding HeaderFontWeight}"/>
        <DatePicker Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Code-Behind with the registered `DependencyProperty`s is:

```
public partial class HeaderedDatePicker : UserControl
{
    public HeaderedDatePicker()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.HeaderFontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        this.Date = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderedDatePicker));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderFontWeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderFontWeight", typeof(FontWeight), typeof(HeaderedDatePicker));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(HeaderedDatePicker));

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontWeight HeaderFontWeight
    {
        get { return (FontWeight)GetValue(HeaderFontWeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderFontWeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DateProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine. Now I want to create another HeaderedControl like a HeaderedComboBox or so. My question now is:

Do I have to write the HeaderProperty and HeaderFontWeightProperty in each Code-Behind-File or is there a way to do this in a base-class?

I tried to create a base-class where the properties are registered, but in the code-behind of the HeaderedDatePicker I couldn't inherit from my class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class main : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(main));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderFontWeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderFontWeight", typeof(FontWeight), typeof(main));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(main));

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontWeight HeaderFontWeight
    {
        get { return (FontWeight)GetValue(HeaderFontWeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderFontWeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DateProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

Then in every UserControl you are supposed to derive from previously declared main.

```
    public partial class HeaderedComboBox : main
{
    public HeaderedComboBox()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    } 
}
```

Finally

```
<local:main x:Class="WpfApplication5.HeaderedComboBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Width="200" Height="50">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Header}" FontWeight="{Binding HeaderFontWeight}"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

Let me know whether it works.

Comment: Yes, it works perfect. I found it out already. But this is a very good example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can register attached property. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753957%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Attached property can be used for any dependency object.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know how I can reuse a registered Property in different UserControls? Or do I have to write DependencyProperty.Register("Header"... in each UserControl where I want to have a Header-Property?